# ngModel and ngFor with Map in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ngmodel

I'm trying to use a string boolean map with ngfor to create a list of checkboxes, but this approach doesn't work.

**.ts**

```
plainMap: Map<string, boolean> = new Map<string, boolean>();
```

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of plainMap">
   <input [(ngModel)]="plainMap.get(item)" type="checkbox" name="item.name" value="item.name">
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more code

Comment: What is `filterMap`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: plainMap is iterable??

Comment: Actually had to add *ngFor="let item of plainMap.keys()" to make it iterable but [(ngModel)] binding doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

my solution is adding a property to component class and call it : "iterablePlainMap" .

add to your .ts :

```
plainMap = new Map<String, boolean>();

iterablePlainMap;

deleteEntry(key: string) {
   this.plainMap.delete(key);
   this.updateIterablePlainMap();
}

setEntry(key: string, value: boolean) {
   this.plainMap.set(key, value);
   this.updateIterablePlainMap();
}

updateIterablePlainMap() {
   this.iterablePlainMap = [];
   this.plainMap.forEach((value, key) => {
       this.iterablePlainMap.push({ value, key });
   });
}
```

actualy setEntry and deleteEntry methods are wraping original set and delete methods of plainMap

and in your .html :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of iterablePlainMap;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
   <input [(ngModel)]="iterablePlainMap[index].value" type="checkbox">
</div>
```